# Show Decimal Keyboard in ReactJS for iOS

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, keyboard

My application is ReactJS. I am using WKWebview on iOS.
I am using number format [react-number-format](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format) for input.

This component not supported(type="number"). You can use only "text,tel,password" type.

`<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*"/>` I can't use this.

So, I wrote the following code.

```
<NumberFormat id="numberFormat" decimalSeparator="," thousandSeparator="." inputMode="decimal" pattern="[0-9]*" .../>
```

Android device screenshot:

[image: Android device keyboard screenshot]

Its correct for me.

IOS device screenshot:

[image: iOS device keyboard screenshot]

Its wrong for me.

I want to see ",(comma)" on the keyboard(decimal pad)

Kindly review and give feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the following line of code.

```
<NumberFormat id="numberFormat" decimalSeparator="," thousandSeparator="." inputMode="decimal" pattern="[0-9],*" .../>
```

But IOS Safari [supporting](https://caniuse.com/#search=inputmode) version 12.2 or higher on inputMode="decimal" .

Thanks.